# splashscreen does not hide

Tags: android, ionic2, splash-screen

I put in app.ts:

```
import { Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
```

---

inside the constructor:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      this.hideSplashScreen()
 }
```

---

the function:

```
hideSplashScreen() {
    if(navigator && navigator.splashscreen) {
    setTimeout(()=> {
       navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 100);
}
```

---

```
in config.xml:
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen"/>
  </feature>
```

---

in typings, my pluginshackyhacky.d.ts is:

```
interface /*PhoneGapNavigator extends*/ Navigator {
  app: any;
  splashscreen: Splashscreen;
}
```

---

In the device and emulator, Slash screen doesn't hide at all...

As soon as I put "splashscreen: Splashscreen;" in the pluginshackyhacky.d.ts file, Ionic serve output in console a 404 error:
http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

There are my errors or the RC0 doesnt't work with slpashscreen?

Pietro

Answer (score 0):

**Update in version ionic 2.3.0**

To hide splashscreen, import splash screen from ionic native and create object to use the method

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
export class your_class{
public splashScreen: SplashScreen;
 constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

**Version 2.0**

Use below code in your constructor

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
 }
```

Ionic native Splashscreen have all the methods for handling splashscreen. Typings is not required

Comment: THANKS. I read somewhere that was not fixed in ionic 2.

Do you know because if I close the app and open again (without memory cleaning) the splash doesn't rise, and the screen is white until the app is ready?

Comment: CLOSED: I put this line:

 <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>

I thought it was the default.